# PostgreSQL call function out refcursor ResultSet next order not working

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, plpgsql, mybatis

**--postgresql function--**

```
create function test(v_param bigin, OUT mycursor refcursor) returns refcursor
language plpgsql
DECLARE
...
BEGIN
l_stmt := "select * from (select * from mytable order by date_column DESC) as t" --order query execut
..
OPEN mycursor FOR EXECUTE l_stmt
END;
```

**--java code--**

```
Connection conn = sqlSession.getConnection();
PreparedStatement preStmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from (select * from mytable order by date_column DESC) as t"); //pl/sql function same query
ResultSet resultSet = preStmt.executeQuery();
while(resultSet.next()) {
   /**
      date_column| etc_column
      2022/06/25 | a
      2022/06/24 | b
      2022/06/23 | c
   **/
   System.out.println(resultSet.getObject(11)) //result row ordered
}
```

**--java code (call function result set ordering problem)--**

```
Connection conn = sqlSession.getConnection();
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
CallableStatement call = conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call test(?) }");
call.registerOutParameter(1, Types.REF_CURSOR);
call.setLong(1, 0L);
call.execute();
ResultSet resultSet = call.getObject(1);
while(resultSet.next()) {
    /**
      date_column| etc_column
      2022/06/24 | b
      2022/06/25 | a
      2022/06/23 | c
   **/
   System.out.println(resultSet.getObject(11)) //result row not ordered
}
```

--Questions.--

**Is the order not guaranteed when getting a cursor by executing a sorted query?**

Comment: Why not make declare the function as `returns table (..)` then use `select * from test(?)` with a `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()`?

Comment: @Laurenz Albe
out refcursor can not return

Comment: @user16320675 just test code, and order of the sql results, not the order of the columns.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Tried it but didn't get the desired result

Comment: Your PL/pgSQL procedure is full of syntax errors.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Perhaps you can provide a complete code sample.